# Do spells such as Hex and enhance ability affect attacks rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e

Do spells such as Hex or enhance ability affect attack rolls made using the affected ability score?

These spells reference advantage/disadvantage on ability checks, but I am unsure whether an attack roll constitutes an ability check.

I did reference these spells specifically in case there is a difference between a specific ruling and the general rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of these spells affect *ability checks*, not *attacks*.

Attacks are not ability checks.

Ability check:

> Ability checks, attack rolls, and saving throws are the
>   three main kinds of d20 rolls, forming the core of the
>   rules of the game. (p4 BD&D)

You can see the difference here. You have an ability check, an attack roll and a saving throw. They are three distinct rolls and when you should do each is called out in the text. The case here is for *ability checks*, these are not attacks and thus the benefit/penalty does not apply.

Comment: There are 3 general types of d20 rolls: Attacks, Ability Checks, and Saves. They are distinct and are always called out explicitly in the rules!

Comment: Yeah, this answer could be much shorter if it just quoted that rule, which makes the situation very explicit.

Comment: @waxeagle I didn't literally mean *just* that rule, but quoting it instead of the separate descriptions of attacks and ability checks.

Comment: @starwed yeah, I just hadn't thought to look for it concisely stated (I honestly didn't think it was), went back through the intro to basic and found the listing. Updated and condenced.